# Advice on IIS log analysis, for finding footprints of hackers

Tags: security, iis, logging

I need to find out how a website was hacked, I have the relevant IIS logs, but since there are too many visitors, It would be nice to have some kind of log analyzer that was not designed to only give you info about traffic but also would let you filter the useless lines of logs and even possibly highlight the suspicious ones.

Do you know any such tool?

Also the website was probably hacked through sql injection, any advice on what too search for? I know I should be looking for weird parameters, but that's not enough because the hacker might have used some forms to POST data, which are not logged in the log files all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page has some good examples on how to use Microsoft's Log Parser

http://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/log-parser-rocks-more-than-50-examples/